# How to check if ftp URL is correct and reachable?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ftp, afnetworking

I'm writing an app for iPad, that must upload/download files from FTP server. So how can I check if FTP URL, that user enters is correct and reachable? I'm using AFNetworking for downloading files, so if I put `UIAlertView` into `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess: failure^` it executes after pretty long time out. Any ideas? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) example. I use it in my project and it is quite fast.

Or look at apple's example [project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but i try both examples, and both of them show that my actual ftp is unreachable, and that's not true

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i found maybe not the best solution, but it actually works pretty well:

```
- (BOOL) isFTPReachable {

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://anonymous@ftpserver"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:10];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *myData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if (myData) {
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;

    }

}

- (void) startSync {

if ([self isFTPReachable]) {

    [self startDownload];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alarma = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection error" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alarma show];
    }
}
```